# How to only process messages from child actors?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-fsm

I built an Akka FSM that spawns two child actors in its constructor and only receives messages from one of them.

```
val lhsRef: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(new PrimitiveNode(tpe)), "lhs")
val rhsRef: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(new PrimitiveNode(tpe)), "rhs")
```

When dealing with incoming events, I want to filter for those that come from `lhsNode`. I tried to achieve this the following way:

```
when(WaitFor1) {
  case Event(event: SomeEventType, _) =>
    // Control flow reaches this point but...
    if (sender == lhsRef) {
      // ...it never enters the if clause.
```

This does not work. In fact, `sender` and `lhsNode`are not equal, even though it's definitely `lhsNode` that sends messages to my FSM.

```
sender()        Actor[akka://default/user/$a#670517729]
lhsNode         Actor[akka://default/user/$a/$a/$b/lhs#-354253348]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare only the names of the `sender` and `lhs`. Check if message is really sent by the `lhsNode`.

```
sender.path.name == "lhs"
```

or

```
sender.path.name = lhsNode.path.name
```

Ensure that the `sender` is the `lhs` actor only. `forward` the message if any other actor is involved in between.

Something like below

```
when(WaitFor1) {
  case Event(event: SomeEventType, _) =>
    // ...
    if (sender.path.name == "lhs") {
      // ....
```

with Pattern match guard

```
when(WaitFor1) {
  case Event(event: SomeEventType, _) (if sender.path.name == "lhs") =>
```

Comment: Your side-comment solved it: Accidental message forwarding was the problem. Thanks! :)